# How to restore tensorflow graph in different notebook in Jupyter?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use tf.train.Saver() in order to save and restore a tensorflow graph. To save the graph I'm proceeding like follows:

```
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    with sess.as_default():
          for ep in range(epoch):
                train_step.run(feed_dict={X: X_train,

                                    Y: y_train.reshape(-1,1)})


          saver.save(sess, 'my_test_model')
```

To restore the model I'm doing like this:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:

            saver.restore(sess, 'my_test_model')

            test_accuracy = sess.run(x,feed_dict={X: X_valid,
                                Y: y_valid.reshape(-1,1)})
            mse_test=loss.eval(feed_dict={X: X_valid,
                                Y: y_valid.reshape(-1,1)})



            print(mse_test)
```

And while doing this in the same notebook everything works perfectly. But when I'm trying to do the same in another notebook the problem begins: the saver is not defined in the new notebook so I'm trying to define it again as tf.train.Saver() and get the error ValueError: No variables to save.

I tried also

```
   saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model.meta')
   saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

but graph variables are not saved in the meta file.

Have anybody faced similar problem? I will appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `saver.restore(sess, 'my_test_model')` work after `import_meta_graph`? Variables are saved with metagraphs, so it should work. You can check on a specific checkpoint with [`tf.contrib.framework.list_variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/list_variables).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried tf.contrib.framework.list_variables and got the list of kernels and biases,so it seems that variables are indeed there. But when I tried to feed dict as above I got an error: Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_2/bias_1. So I understand that those variables should be somehow initialized again (smth like tf.global_variables_initializer()
) but I don't know how to do it. get_tensor_by_name is not a good idea here  n as in initial graph Im using  Keras Dense to define the layers.

Comment: Ah, so you don't want to use the MetaGraph, you want to restore into the variables associated with Python objects. Maybe check the names from `list_variables` against `tf.global_variables()`? Are the names different?

Comment: I want to be able to use an already trained TensorFlow model in another script/jupyter notebook, and I cannot figure out all the steps I need to perform in order to do so. Currently I get to this points: I've restored metagraph, and try to evaluate the variables by name sess.run('loss:0',feed_dict={'x:0': X_valid.reshape(-1,11),
    'y:0': y_valid.reshape(-1,1)}), but get an error of wrong shape (even though exactly this data is fed into original model and everything works )

Comment: Hard to say anything about the shape issues without seeing code to reproduce it.